# Stop Chrome from entering my bank password automatically

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, autocomplete

Chrome automatically enters my bank password when I go to the Bank site.  How do I stop this?

Answer (score 5):

Click on the button on the upper right with 3 lines select "Settings" then select "Settings" from the left-hand menu then "Show advanced settings" from the bottom of the page, go to "Passwords and forms" and click on "Manage passwords" just behind "Offer to save your web passwords"

Here you can delete the password for the website of your bank

Comment: Chrome could easily auto-save it again...

Comment: @zyboxenterprises It gives you a prompt when it does, just click `Never for this site` or whatever the wording is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, you can go advance tap and go manage password. Then delete the saved password among all the website. It will work even though other website can be login automatically.

Comment: Won't that make chrome remember it again afterwards though?

Answer (score -2):

Go to "Settings" then select "Settings" from the left-hand menu then "Show advanced settings" from the bottom of the page, go to "Passwords and forms" and deselect "Enable Auto-fill to fill in web forms in a single click. "

Comment: This will actually disable all websites, not just the bank. And the login info for the bank is still stored on the computer.

Comment: You should offer constructive answer not just negations to other answers; the author of the post did not tell that he wants to delete the password/s; moreover, he did not mention that he wants login info to be deleted from his computer; "read twice, answer once"

Comment: @b0s0r0gu: Chill down and accept some criticism, even though he didn't even really criticize you, just pointed out a really important fact that the OP should be beware of if choosing this option.

Comment: @Yogu: I love constructive critics and I hate far-from-subject ones; Roald van Doorn criticize on some hypotheses not written explicitly by post's author. In fact, my answer solves the posted issue but Roald van Doorn intervenes and brings some critics about issues which are not stated by author of the post.

Comment: Upvoted: It's a viable solution, just not an ideal one.